# вывести кастомные данные в цикле блога Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте, есть цикл который выводит записи блога из определенной рубрики, мне нужно передать в отдельный див отдельную строку. То есть я на странице записи создаю определенный див с неважно какой информацией и мне нужно как-то этот див в цикл закинуть. Я почти ничего не понимаю в php. Может кто подскажет? Спасибо

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
    query_posts('cat=7');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога
                ?>
    <div class = "item">
    <div class="item_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <div class = "item_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class = "item_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(10); ?></div>
        <a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class = "item_link">Подробнее</a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
          endif;
    /* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, чтобы не было сбоя. */
          wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Выкинуть этот код и гуглить почему не нужно использовать `query_posts`  (а "див в цикл закинуть" это вообще.. достаньте меня из под стола...)

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за полезный коммент

Comment: Создайте любой `div` внутри вашего цикла и он по-любому выведется, не важно какую информацию он содержит (статическую или динамическую). А вопрос то собственно в чем?

Comment: Надеюсь, погуглил прежде чем "благодарить" :)

Comment: @eugene_v ну я не понимаю как это сделать. Ну то есть я создал див (неважно какой селектор) в шаблоне записи и я хочу чтобы этот селектор выводился с цикле на странице блога, а не отделньой записи

Comment: Этот див должен быть в каждом посту в цикле на странице блога или один раз (как обычно выводят блок контекстной рекламы между постами)?

Comment: @eugene_v в каждом посту. Этот блок будет в шаблоне

Comment: Вы обратили внимание, что в вашем коде, который вы указали в описании есть блок с заголовком поста ‘class=“item_title”’ вот он выводится в каждом посте в цикле. Добавьте перед ним или после него свой div с произвольным текстом и посмотрите результат

Comment: @eugene_v и этот произвольный текст будет один и тот же и будет редактируем только из этого шаблона. Мне нужно добавлять произвольный текст именно в шаблоне записи! то есть есть single.php которая является шаблонов для бесконечного количества записей, а есть page-blog.php например где эти записи выводятся как анонсы с миниатюрой, татйлом и коротким содержанием, например. А вот мне нужно еще что бы на page-blog.php выводился помимо миниатюры, тайтла, короткоо содержания еще мой кастомный блок, содержание которого будет определятся в каждой отдельной записи, то есть в single.php

Comment: Не совсем понял. Это мы говорим о выводе. Если вы укажите в single.php то он выведется внутри поста, если в шаблоне page-blog.php то он будет выводиться вместе с кратким описанием. А вот чтоб из админки его редактировать, то нужно ещё создать кастомные поля (можете использовать ACF)

Comment: @eugene_v да я использую кастомные поля, но речь не об этом. Не понимаю что я не так говорю. Ну вот я же могу в page-blog.php выводить тайтл и картинку всех записей по очереди, так? но мне нужно кроме тайтла и картинки еще вывести какой-то произвольный текст, который будет записан именно в каждой отдельной записи, текст будет постоянно разный, но в одной блоке, назовем его "кастомный блок". И вот мне надо чтобы в page-blog.php выводился тайтл, картинки и "кастомный блок".

Answer (score 0):

Вот я добавил в ваш код абстрактный кастом филд:

```
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
        query_posts('cat=7');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога
            ?>
        <div class="item">
        <div class="item_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
            <div class="item_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="item_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(10); ?></div>
            <div class="custom_field"><?php the_field('custom_field'); ?></div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class = "item_link">Подробнее</a></div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
              endif;
        /* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, чтобы не было сбоя. */
      wp_reset_query();?>
```

Что вам здесь не понятно? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Не нужен тут `query_posts`. Даже опасен.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, сейчас конкретно спрашивают, как вывести кастом филд

Comment: Это не "другой вопрос", а опасный ответ.

Comment: Причём здесь опасный ответ, у человека есть написанный код, не я его ему навязывал, я просто скопировал код и добавил строку. Если у вас так много времени комментировать каждый коммент, так напишите тогда “безопасный ответ”. Что за привычка и сам толком не ответил и других обосрал

Comment: При том что думать надо что писать в паблике.

Comment: >и сам толком не ответил Я-то ответил. Но я не виноват, что не все могут понять.

Comment: Я видел ваш ответ «достаньте меня из-под стола» Я так понимаю, что это был осмысленный ответ в паблике?

Comment: Это уже второй ответ который должен был запустить голову ТСу. А ты только его половину увидел. А первый, основной, вообще  для тебя как и для ТСа оказался прозрачен  :(